# Inserting rows to a table which causes a dashboard to disappear

Tags: r, shinydashboard, rhandsontable

I have a dashboard with two data tables. The dashboard is disappearing when I insert new rows to these tables. It happens, especially, when I insert rows to the `Table 2` whose data gets calculated and aggregated in the first column of the `Table 1` as shown below:

Table 1
`Cost of a batch of goods` = `Cost of purchase` + `Cost of production`

Table2
`Cost of purchase` = `Purchase price` + `Import duties`

As you saw above, the column titled `Cost of purchase` of the `Table 1` = `Table 2`

Can someone help me make the dashboard not disappearing when rows are inserted to both of the tables independent of each other?

To firuge out the problem with the disappearing dashboard in result of inserting new rows, please, check the script below:

```
"Cost of goods sold" = data.table(
        "Cost of purchase" = as.numeric(0),
        "Cost of production" = as.numeric(0),
        "Cost of a batch of goods" = as.numeric(0))

"Cost of purchase" = data.table(    
        "Purchase price" = as.numeric(0),
        "Import duties" = as.numeric(0))


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Financial Reporting"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
    menuItem("Measurement", tabName = "Measurement", 
      menuSubItem("COGS calculation", tabName = "tableV1300_1")
   )
 ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tableV1300_1",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            "Cost of goods sold",
            width = 12,
            rHandsontableOutput("TableV1300_1_1"),
            tags$style(type="text/css", "#TableV1300_1_1 th {font-weight:bold;}")
      ),
          column(
            "Cost of purchase",
            width = 12,
            rHandsontableOutput("TableV1300_1_2"),
            tags$style(type="text/css", "#TableV1300_1_2 th {font-weight:bold;}")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {

data <- reactiveValues()

observe({
        input$recalc
        data$`COGS` <- as.data.frame(`Cost of goods sold`)
        data$`COP` <- as.data.frame(`Cost of purchase`)
})

observe({
        if(!is.null(input$TableV1300_1_1))
        data$`COGS` <- hot_to_r(input$TableV1300_1_1)
})

observe({
        if(!is.null(input$TableV1300_1_2))
        data$`COP` <- hot_to_r(input$TableV1300_1_2)
})

    observe({data$`COGS`$`Cost of a batch of goods` <- data$`COGS`$`Cost of purchase` + 
                           data$`COGS`$`Cost of production` 
    })

observe({data$`COGS`$`Cost of purchase` <-
        data$`COP`$`Purchase price` +
        data$`COP`$`Import duties`
})

output$TableV1300_1_1 <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(data$`COGS`, stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |> 
        hot_cols(colWidths = c(150, 150, 150))
})

output$TableV1300_1_2 <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(data$`COP`, stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |> 
        hot_cols(colWidths = c(150, 150))
})

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. The first table has only row. When you insert a row in the second table, this one has two rows, so you cannot do ```data$`COGS`$`Cost of purchase` <- data$`COP`$`Purchase price` + data$`COP`$`Purchase price````. Don't you want to sum instead?